# Backbone Relational not setting reverse relations properly?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-relational

I'm trying to use [Backbone.Relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) to set up some associations in my app.

Basically I have Backbone `Search` and `Service` models. A Search has a `ServiceList` collection which contains many services.

However, I don't seem to be able to access the parent Search from within the Service initializer. When I try to log the parent search I get `null`. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

My Search model is set up like so (code might have syntax errors, I'm translating from coffeescript on the fly):

```
var Search = new Backbone.RelationalModel({
  urlRoot: '/searches',

  relations: [{
    type: Backbone.HasMany,
    key: 'services',
    relatedModel: 'Service',
    collectionType: 'ServiceList',
    reverseRelation: {
      key: 'search'
    }
  }],

  initialize: function(options) {
    // => Search "has services:", ServiceList
    console.log this, "has services:", @get('services');
  }
});


var Service = new Backbone.RelationalModel
  initialize: function() {
    // => Service "in" null
    console.log this, "in", @get('search');
  }
});
```

Or if you prefer CoffeeScript:

```
class Search extends Backbone.RelationalModel
  urlRoot: '/searches'

  relations: [
    type: Backbone.HasMany
    key: 'services'
    relatedModel: 'Service'
    collectionType: 'ServiceList'
    reverseRelation:
      key: 'search'
  ]

  initialize: (options) ->
    // => Search "has services:", ServiceList
    console.log this, "has services:", @get('services')



class Service extends Backbone.RelationalModel
  initialize: ->
    // => Service "in" null
    console.log this, "in", @get('search')
```

Comment: Yes, the JS you posted is very not-correct.  Can you post the original coffeescript?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short Answer**

You simply don't have access to the reverse relation's value in the Service's initialize method.

The value for the reverse relation is set after the initialize has completed.

**Longer Answer**

Assuming this javascript:

```
Search = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
  urlRoot: '/searches',

  relations: [{
    type: Backbone.HasMany,
    key: 'services',
    relatedModel: 'Service',
    reverseRelation: {
      key: 'search'
    }
  }],

  initialize: function(options) {
    console.log(this, "has services:", this.get('services'));
  }
});


Service = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    console.log(this, "in", this.get('search'));
  }
});
```

When you create a new Search model with related Services:

```
s1 = new Search({name:"Some Search",services:[{name:"service1"},{name:"service2"}]});
```

What's going to happen is:

```
new Service model created (for service1) - name set to "service1"
  (but, since what got passed to the model for properties is {name:"service1"}
   you can see how this model cannot know its reverse relation yet.)
new Service model created (for service2) - name set to "service2"
  (same as above)
new Search model created (for 'some search')
  name set to 'some search'
  service1 Service model added to Search.services
    (triggers 'update:search' event on Service1 model)
  service2 Service model added to Search services
    (triggers 'update:search' event on Service2 model)
```

It isn't until the service1 and service2 Service models are added to the Search.services collection that the reverse relations on service1.search and service2.search are set.

Here's a JS fiddle that shows the order of operations in the console:  http://jsfiddle.net/MNh7N/6/